# React Native PermissionsAndroid doesn't include READ_MEDIA_IMAGES. How to work around this?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, permissions, android-permissions, react-native-permissions

I'm using [react-native-camera-roll/camera-roll@5.2.0](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll) in my React Native app. For Android 13, the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission has been [replaced](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) by READ_MEDIA_IMAGES. I use the following code to check if permission has been granted:

```
const permission = Platform.Version >= 33 ? PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES : PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;

const hasPermission = await PermissionsAndroid.check(permission);
```

However, `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS` doesn't contain `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, so `permission` is `undefined`. Passing `undefined` to `PermissionsAndroid.check()` makes the app hang.

**What I Want To Know:**

I'm using react-native@0.65.3. PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES doesn't become available until 0.70, so unless I update to 0.70, `permission` will always be `undefined`. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the solutions is to use the separate well maintained library for permissions handling called https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions

If you want to get it from RN it should be included in 0.71 based on this PR https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/0a854c7c8b7ffc382c43fa460651a4b4de34c3c7

Based on PR above you also can create a patch from your local changes using https://github.com/ds300/patch-package. However, if you want to use patched version of RN you should follow this instruction https://reactnative.dev/contributing/how-to-build-from-source

Comment: I'm using react-native-permissions now, thanks! Could you tell me what the difference is between using react-native-permissions for Android and using PermissionsAndroid from RN?

Comment: @gkeenley this module provides unified abstraction and because it is a separate module, you don't need to think about the RN version. You can read more about it https://reactnative.dev/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#lean-core-removals