# Permission is not being requested on Android

Tags: javascript, android, permissions

I'm in a react native project and I'm taking a beating so I need to ask for Video and Image permission. I've already put the users in the androidmanifest

import {
PermissionsAndroid,
Rationale,
} from 'react-native';
export default function Bin({ navigation }) {

```
const requestCameraPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
        {
          title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
          message:
            "Cool Photo App needs access to your camera " +
            "so you can take awesome pictures.",
          buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
          buttonNegative: "Cancel",
          buttonPositive: "OK"
        }
      );
      if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
        console.log("You can use the camera");
      } else {
        console.log("Camera permission denied");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES,
        {
          title: "Cool Photo App Camera Permission",
      ` No good. For taking pictures you need CAMERA permission.  READ_,MEDIA_IMAGES is if you list storage for images.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

The permission constant for reading media images is not available by default in PermissionsAndroid.

**Solution #1**

You can request the generic `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission instead of the `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`.

**Solution #2**

You can handle it using a third party library called [react-native-permissions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-permissions), You can check this old question for more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75010079/react-native-permissionsandroid-doesnt-include-read-media-images-how-to-work-a).